# How to Set Multiple Click Listener to AutoCompleteTextView in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, autocompletetextview, onitemclicklistener, onitemlongclicklistener

I have an **AutoCompleteTextView** that will show a list of Hints when type in few keyword that match with its ArrayAdapter Data.

Currently, I have set an **AdapterView.OnItemClickListener** so when user click on the Hint, the soft keyboard on screen will be close.

**What I trying to achieve :**

- I would like to add a functionality that allow user to Delete the Data of the Hint from the Database, so I was thinking to **add another ClickListener for the AdapterView** such as **LongClickListener**, so when user LongClick on the Hint, it will trigger a Dialog Pop Out and prompt the Delete Confirmation from the User.

I been search for how to set LongClickListener on Autocomplete, however I could not find any solution on the net.

I believe it is important to ensure the **Click Listen** able to obtain the **position(in Int)** or **text data(in String)** of the Hint as I would need to determine what are the Data that being selected and I can tell the Database to delete it.

**My Questions:**

How can I set a **Long Click Listener** for the AutoCompleteTextView that will also obtain the selected Hint position?

Any other solution that could help to resolve what I trying to achieve is welcome, thank you.

**Note:** I would like to keep the functionality of the hide soft keyboard when Hint is selected. I accept **Answer In Java Language** as well.

**What I have done so far :**

```
 // Get an ArrayList<String> from database and declare to remarkList
 val remarkList: ArrayList<String> = getDataFromDatabase() 

 // Set remarkList Data into ArrayAdapter
 val adapter = ArrayAdapter(context!!, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, remarkList)

 // Set ArrayAdapter to AutoCompleteTextView
 autoComplete_remarks.setAdapter<ArrayAdapter<String>>(adapter)

        // When click the hint selection, will trigger close keyboard function
        autoComplete_remarks.onItemClickListener =
                AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _: AdapterView<*>, _: View, position: Int, _: Long ->

                    hideKeyboard(activity!!)
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have created the Custom Adapter Class for the AutoCompleteTextView, Basically This Custom Adapter, in the `getView` function will create an Unique Individual Listener for each `TextView` that will be pop out by the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

**Note:** The `TextView` results that pop out by the `AutoCompleteTextView` is Customizable through `inner class ListFilter: Filter()` and `override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults)` function

**Custom Adapter Class**

```
class AutoCompleteTextViewCustomAdapter(context: Context, resource: Int, data: ArrayList<String>): ArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource) {

    private var mListener: IOnItemListener? = null

    private var dataList: List <String>? = data
    private val listFilter = ListFilter()
    private var dataListAllItems: List<String>? = null

    override fun getView(position: Int, view: View? , parent: ViewGroup): View {
        var adapterView = view

        // using Custom XML View
        if (adapterView == null) {
                adapterView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_row_text, parent, false)
        }

        val textView = adapterView!!.findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
        textView.text = getItem(position)

        // Custom OnClickListener Setup
        textView.setOnLongClickListener {
            mListener?.onLongClick("Pass Data")
            true
        }
        // Custom OnClickListener Setup
        textView.setOnClickListener {
            mListener?.onSingleClick("Pass Data")
        }

        return adapterView
    }

    // Custom OnClickListener Setup
    fun setListener(listener : IOnItemListener) {
        mListener = listener
    }

    // Custom OnClickListener Setup that will be Called from the Activity/Fragment
    interface IOnItemListener {
        fun onLongClick(dataToBePass : String)
        fun onSingleClick(dataToBePass : String)
    }

    // Custom Adapter Setup for AutoCompleteTextView
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return dataList!!.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): String ? {
        return dataList!![position]
    }

    override fun getFilter() : Filter {
        return listFilter
    }

    inner class ListFilter: Filter() {
        ..// Filtering Logic
        return results
    }

    override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults) {
        ..// Filtering Logic
    }
}
```

So, when each `TextView` that pop out by the `AutoCompleteTextView` being onClick or onLongClick, the **override method** in `AutoCompleteTextViewCustomAdapter.IOnItemListener` will be called to perform logic function that you desire.

**Activity/Fragment**

```
val adapter = AutoCompleteTextViewCustomAdapter(context!!, R.layout.list_row_text, dataList).also {

            //Setup the OnClickListener what to perform when the TextView of the Adapter if being onClick
            it.setListener(object : AutoCompleteTextViewCustomAdapter.IOnItemListener {
                override fun onLongClick(dataReceived: String) {
                    // DO SOMETHING
                }

                override fun onSingleClick(dataReceived: String) {
                    // DO SOMETHING
                }
            })
        }

        // Set the adapter to the AutoCompleteTextView View that define in your XML File
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter)
```

So far this solution work for my Scenario, in short, to having a **Multiple Click Listener to AutoCompleteTextView**, we cannot use the **Default Adapter** as they only support Single onClickListener, so we have to Create Custom Adapter to customize and **setup ALL the ClickListener** to support multiple onClick Listener.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have multiple click listeners, you should build a custom `Adapter` with custom item layout.

```
class CustomAdapter(context: Context?, resource: Int) : ArrayAdapter<Data>(context, resource) {
    private var mListener : IOnItemListener? = null

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View? {
        var convertView = convertView

        // Inflate layout

        // Listeners
        val textViewItem = convertView!!.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem) as TextView

        textViewItem.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            mListener?.onClick(...)
        })

        textViewItem.setOnLongClickListener(View.OnLongClickListener {
            mListener?.onLongClick(...)
        })

        return convertView;
    }

    fun setListener(listener: IOnItemListener) {
        mListener = listener
    }

    interface IOnItemListener {
        fun onClick(...)
        fun onLongClick(...)
    }
}
```

Then somewhere else, call

```
val adapter : CustomAdapter = CustomAdapter(context, R.layout...)
adapter.setListener(object: IOnItemListener())
```